# How to set multiple Angular UI-router resolve statements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to stop a situation where the page loads prior to the data, so you get the view updating whilst page is loading.

In UI-router, you can set a 'resolve' which can run a method and retrieve data prior to loading page, which is working fantastically, but I seem to only be able to do this for one method. Is there a way to run multiple methods in a resolve prior to loading the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `resolve` can receive an object as well. And each property would have to be resolved before the controller, so then the state could be achieved.

> Each of the objects in resolve below must be resolved (via `deferred.resolve()` if they are a `promise`) before the `controller` is instantiated. Notice how each resolve object is injected as a parameter into the controller ([UI-Router docs for resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)).

For example:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    resolve: {
        resolve0: function () { // resolve with plain value
            return 'somedata';
        },
        resolve1: function ($q) { // resolve with promise
            return $q.resolve('somedata');
        },
        resolve2: function ($q) { // reject with promise, it will preven state to finish change
            return $q.reject('some error');
        }
    }
}
```